How many students have a cat?

In a classroom of $100$ students, each student owns at least one pet: a dog, a cat, and/or a bird. If $41$ students have a dog, $13$ students have only a bird, $22$ students have a cat and a bird, and $8$ students have a dog and a cat, how many students have a cat?

I want to check if my answer is correct.
In a classroom of 100 students, we are given the following information:

$41$ students have a dog.
$13$ students have only a bird.
$22$ students have a cat and a bird.
$8$ students have a dog and a cat.

We are asked to find how many students have a cat.

$D$: set of students with a dog.
$C$: set of students with a cat.
$B$: set of students with a bird.

$|D| = 41, \quad |B \setminus (D \cup C)| = 13, \quad |C \cap B| = 22, \quad |C \cap D| = 8.$
The number of students who have only a dog is:
$|D \setminus (C \cup B)| = 41 - 8 = 33.$
The number of students with a bird is:
$|B| = 13 \text{ (only a bird)} + 22 \text{ (cat and bird)} = 35.$
Now, the remaining students, after accounting for those with only a bird and only a dog, are:
$100 - 13 - 33 = 54.$
Thus, the number of students with a cat is:
$|C| = 22 \text{ (cat and bird)} + 8 \text{ (dog and cat)} + (54 - 22 - 8) = 54.$
Therefore, the total number of students who have a cat is $54.$

Ya! You're a good to go! Kudos

You asked this question last week and I already answered it https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4982727/209006

A comment, following the posted question, has answered the OP's (i.e. original poster's) specific question.
I advise a truth table, rather than a venn diagram or the approach taken by the OP, whenever there are three or more categories.
\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}
\hline                       
\text{Variable} & \text{Dog} & \text{Cat} & \text{Bird}  \\ \hline                       
x_1 & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
x_2 & \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{F} \\ \hline
x_3 & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\ \hline
x_4 & \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\ \hline
x_5 & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\ \hline
x_6 & \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{F} \\ \hline
x_7 & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\ \hline
x_8 & \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\ \hline
\end{array}
From the constraints:
     x_1  x_2  x_3  x_4  x_5  x_6  x_7  x_8
E-1:  1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0   =  100
E-2:                                     1   =    0
...................................................
E-3:  1    1    1    1                       =   41
E-4:                                1        =   13
E-5:  1                   1                  =   22
E-6:  1    1                                 =    8
...................................................
G  :  1    1              1    1             =    ?

Using E-1 and E-4:

E-7: $~x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 100 - 13 = 87.$

Using E-3 and E-6:

E-8: $~x_3 + x_4 = 41 - 8 = 33.$

Therefore, the computation for equation G is $~87 - 33 = 54.$
Equation E-2 is included, only for clarity.
Further, equation E-5 is completely unused, in my approach.

Thank you for your comment! Can you explain a bit more about the variables x, E, and G? I am not quite sure I follow.

@ShsTht Your question is too vague.  Instead, please re-read my answer, line by line, and stop on the very first line that confuses you.  Then leave a comment-question, immediately following this answer, that quotes that line, and describes your confusion.

Okay, in the table below the truth table, what do $E$-1, ..., $E$-6 represent?

@ShsTht E-1,...,E-6 represent equations, in terms of the variables $~x_1,\cdots,x_8~$ based on the constraints.  For example, the constraint that there are $~100~$ students, each of whom owns at least one pet, is represented by the two equations:  $$x_1 + \cdots + x_7 = 100, ~x_8 = 0.$$  Note that the truth table assigns each of the variables $~x_1,\cdots,x_8~$ to one of the $~8~$ possible rows in the truth table.

Okay, so I assume $x_8$ indicates the number of students with all three pets which is $0$. Is this the case? If yes, how can we confidently say so?

@ShsTht you have mis-read the 8th row of the truth table.  $~x_8~$ indicates the number of students who have no pets.  In contrast, $~x_1~$ represents the number of students who have all three pets.  Note that the problem does not require that exact values be computed for each of the variables $~x_1,x_2,x_5,x_6.~$  Instead, the problem merely requires that the sum $~(x_1 + x_2 + x_5 + x_6)~$ be deduced.

Thank you soo much!! I understood it now.

This truth table is giving exactly the same information as I gave in matrix form when you previously asked this question

@jonnybolton16 After reviewing your corresponding answer, I have to disagree here.  Consider your target audience, which in this case is totally new to this type of analysis.  On the one hand, I feel that by first creating a truth table chart, and then mapping out the linear equations, I have made it simpler for the new student to grapple with.  Then, consider that despite my efforts, the original poster still posted three separate comment/questions, following my answer, to resolve his confusion.  ...see next comment

@jonnybolton16 I suspect that the original poster re-posted the question because they did not fully understand your answer.  I did examine the comment/questions following your answer, where you addressed any reported confusion from the original poster.  I surmise that in this situation, it is better to forgo elegance, and break the matrix presentation into a truth table followed by a chart of linear equations.  That is, don't mention a matrix at all.

@jonnybolton16 Also, for what it's worth, your comment doesn't seem to have the @ShsTht label, which indicates that ShsTht was not flagged by your comment.
